# Leaderboard based on location

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am working on an android game(which is created using Unity3d engine) and I was trying to use google game service features when I stumbled upon a question implementing leaderboards.

Is there any way to sort player scores based on their location?

I want players to know their rank in their country, continent, etc. Something like google's time based leaderboards(daily, weekly and monthly)

Do I have to implement this feature myself? If so leave your thoughts and ideas.

Comment: hi, have you found a solution?

Comment: Hi @beatsspam, no I've not fount any solutions implementing the leaderboard with help of google play services. What I ended up doing was ditching the feature and forgetting about it. But you can always implement that and more complex sort of stuff if you had your own server. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Creating your own leaderboard means you have to write a Server (i.e. a HTTP Server) that can store the players, the scores and the locations (preferably in a database).
Getting the location of your users depends on the final build (browser, app, windows exe, etc.)

Comment: Shoot! my game does not have a server, thought it might be possible with help of google play services... tnx for the answer btw.

Comment: I am not familiar with google play services, maybe they offer something like that